# Windows 10 -- laptop to laptop migration -- where is the Easy button?

Tags: windows-10, migration

I can't believe it is 2020 and I am asking this....

I have a Surface Go 2 (with the wimpy CPU). Win10. Current. Has maybe six apps on it, and a lot of files in many dirs.

I am getting a new Surface.

Where is the Easy button (or utility) to migrate?

Comment: You might check if the following tool is helpful with you:https://www.easeus.com/pc-transfer/windows-10-migration-tool.html

Comment: Whatever you do don't try to migrate windows.  Only migrate your files and reinstall everything else.  Go clean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to simply hit the network share of the old laptop and copy over files, and reinstall all the apps, and reset my various taskbar and display settings.

What a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about your files I'd recommend to get a USB drive or maybe even an external HDD. Just copy them over and you're done.
Depending on how accessible the drive in your old laptop is you could also use that as an external HDD or even put that one in the new laptop, though I recommend a fresh installation of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Possible paths forward:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4229823/moving-to-a-windows-10-pc

http://www.zinstall.com/how-to/how-to-transfer-from-Windows-10-to-windows-10-with-programs-and-files

Have not tried them yet